# Slicing vs Upcasting :: Is my understanding correct?

Tags: c++

Let A be the base class and B be it's publicly derived class.

```
B b;
```

Slicing:

```
A a = b;
```

Upcasting:

```
A* p = &b; // p is a pointer variable of type A
A& r = b; // r is a reference variable of type A
```

Is this correct? Please share similar examples to illustrate the two concepts if possible.

Comment: `p` is a pointer variable of type *pointer to `A`* .

Comment: The type of the variable `r` is *reference to `A`*, however the type of the expression `r` is `A`. Clear? :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

**Object slicing** happens when a derived class object is assigned to a base class object, additional attributes of a derived class object are sliced off to form the base class object.

So yes, if you have a base class A

```
class A{
  public:
    int x;
    char y;
};
```

and a class B derived publically from A with some extra data members,

```
class B:public A{
  public:
    int z;
};
```

doing `A a = b;`  will slice off 'z'.

**Upcasting** is conversion of pointer or reference of derived class type to pointer or reference of base class type, going up in the inheritance tree.

```
B objB;
A *objA = &objB;
```

Just to bring more light on this subject, you can convert a base-class pointer(reference) to a derived-class pointer (reference).It is called **downcasting**(opposite to upcasting).

`B *objB = (B *) &A;`

But there's no way you can assign a base class object to a derived class object.

Cheers!